# XPages - How do I specify 'selectedTab' for a repeated Dojo Accordion control

Tags: dynamic, dojo, xpages, accordion, repeat

I am trying to preserve the last selected state of a dynamic accordion control by storing the selectedTab ID in a sessionScope variable and then specifying this value as the 'selectedTab' parameter for the Accordion Container when the control loads/refreshes rather than defaulting to the first tab.

The code below is a simple XPage that demonstrates where I currently am, it stores the ID of the selected Accordion Tab but continues to default to the first Tab on refresh.....could someone please point out where I'm going wrong.

'Create controls at page creation' is checked (true)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
xmlns:debug="http://www.openntf.org/xsp/debugtoolbar">
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.tabLabels = ["Tab1","Tab 2","Tab 3"];

if (!sessionScope.containsKey("openTab")){sessionScope.openTab = ""};
}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
<xe:djAccordionContainer id="djAccordionContainer1"
    selectedTab="#{javascript:sessionScope.openTab}">
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{sessionScope.tabLabels}"
    var="tabs" indexVar="tabIndex" repeatControls="true">
    <xe:djAccordionPane style="font-weight:bold"
        title="#{javascript:tabs}">
        <xe:this.id><![CDATA[${javascript:"djAccordionPane" + tabIndex}]]>
</xe:this.id>
        <xp:label value="Label" id="label7"></xp:label>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:label value="Label" id="label8"></xp:label>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:label value="Label" id="label9"></xp:label>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onShow" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">             
<xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.openTab =  
this.getParent().getId();}]]></xe:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xe:djAccordionPane>
</xp:repeat>    
<xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="doLayout" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
</xe:djAccordionContainer>
<xp:span style="font-weight:bold"></xp:span>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: I am still looking for an answer to this question is anyone able to help ?